# How to fix certificate unknown error from chrome v73

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, client-certificates, self-signed

I am getting an error when using my certificate to connect to an offline device.
 TLS 1.2 Alert Level Fatal: Certificate Unknown is the error that is seen in wire shark.

Seeing this behavior in Chrome Version 73.0.3683.103 (Official Build) (64-bit) and later.
The same scenario was working properly in chrome 72.

Tried to add our self signed certificate to the chrome certificate store but still getting the same error.

Not sure whether anything is wrong with the certificate, as after a few refreshes the web page loads properly.

Some connections are being rejected with this error but some connections are being accepted which is causing the page to load after a few refreshes.

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: No, contacted chrome support ,they recommended to use a valid certificate although the issue is fixed with the new certificate, not sure what causes the issue.

Comment: I speculate that Chrome sends the `Alert` on discovery of an invalid certificate, this is then "rectified" by starting the handshake again, after checking that's okay with the user (possibly using the user's earlier preferences). This is a bug, imo.